# How do you implement Websocket to your android application

Tags: java, android, websocket, artificial-intelligence

So I'm a beginner in developing android application i wanna know how do you implement websocket to my android application so that i can get the data's from our server

I have tried deserialization the data from json to java so that they'll be able to communicate once the connection is established

```
package com.example.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.BatteryManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.java_websocket.client.WebSocketClient;
import org.java_websocket.handshake.ServerHandshake;

import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebSocketClient mWebSocketClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        connectWebSocket();

    }

    private void connectWebSocket() {

        URI uri;
        try {
            uri = new URI("ws://10.24.204.215:9090");
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        mWebSocketClient = new WebSocketClient(uri) {
            @Override
            public void onOpen(ServerHandshake handshakedata) {
                Log.i("Websocket", "Opened");
                mWebSocketClient.send("Hello from" + Build.MANUFACTURER + " " + Build.MODEL );

            }

            @Override
            public void onMessage(String s) {
                final String uiview = s;
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.uiview);
                        textView.setText(textView.getText() + "\n" + uiview);
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onClose(int i, String s, boolean b) {
                Log.i("Websocket", "Closed" + s);

            }


            @Override
            public void onError(Exception e) {
                Log.i("Websocket", "Error" + e.getMessage());

            }
        };
        mWebSocketClient.connect();
    }

    IntentFilter iFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);

    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittxt);
       String mWebSocketClient = editText.getText().toString();
        editText.setText("");
    }
}
```

It wont let me display gather the data's from the WS to display it to my mobile screen.

Comment: check this: [https://socket.io/blog/native-socket-io-and-android/](https://socket.io/blog/native-socket-io-and-android/)